# How to fix MS Access Form Combobox error in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, combobox

I originally had my combobox cbSortOrder defined in the form as a fixed Value List. I am now attempting to set this in VBA code, using an array. I have tried with a variant and string array but do not think my issue is connected with that but is something to do with the combobox definition.

When attempting to set these values in a With statement, I get the Object Doesn't Support Method error.

I have attached screenprints of the actual error and properties of my combobox.

[image: Error]
[image: Combo box general properties]
[image: Data properties]

Comment: You could use an Access _CallBack_ function for this. Example code: [VBA.CallBack](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use collections as row source in Access. A Row Source Type of `Value List` refers to a comma (or semicolon) separated text (depends on the list separator setting in Windows).

If you don't want to use such a value list, use a Row Source Type of `Table/Query` and specify a table or query name. You can also insert a SELECT statement directly into this field.

This also means, that you must store the entries in a table for this Row Source Type. You can also use a local table instead of a table in the back-end.

Also, the `ComboBox` has no `List` property. Use the `RowSource` property instead. In the code behind of the form you can omit the `Forms("formName")` part.

```vb
With cbSortOrder
    .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    .RowSource = "SELECT Id, Description FROM tlkpSortOrder ORDER BY Description"
End With
```

or

```vb
With cbSortOrder
    .ColumnCount = 2    ' If you have and id and a text
    .ColumnWidths = "0" ' Hides the Id column
    .RowSourceType = "Value List"
    .RowSource = "1,Ascending,2,Descending,3,Undefined"
End With
```

See also: [ComboBox.RowSourceType property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.rowsourcetype?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm11378);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: I had actually formatted an original comma separated string into an array() because I misunderstood what was expected. I have now got a list of 20 values so that looks ok. However, I would like to use VBA to preselect one of these. I thought the ListIndex property was correct and writeable. However, whether my index value is a long number or integer, I get Run Time error 777 stating I have used Listindex incorrectly. My code is below with lIndex set to 10 (20 list entries in the combobox.   Forms("ListBasicReportData").cbSortOrder.ListIndex = lIndex        I have also tried in a With statement

Comment: The combobox apparently needs to be focused to use this property. Either set the `Value` instead or call `SetFocus` on the cb before assigning the `ListIndex`.

Comment: Setting the value did the job. setfocus did not work at all. What works and s=doesn't work for Combobox objects is very confusing. Thanks.